Reading from a queue in sounddevice with a long lag
I writing a script for real-time speech translation. Sound from a microphone is put in a python queue, with another process getting sound chunks from the queue, transforming speech into text and translating the text in pieces which are printed out.
What happens is that there is a variable lag between speaking and translation. It can be as long as 30-60 seconds or even longer. Sometimes transcription and translation catch up with speaking but usually a long backlog builds up and is processed after the speech ends.
I recorded a very detailed log of each action with timing and found that transcription and translation are fast enough (less than a second per chunk) and the delays are mostly caused by slow reading from the queue.
The computer does not seem to be overloaded, the CPU and GPU fans don't even start. So the question is what could be the reason and how can I reduce the lag?
A simplified version of the script is below. Some code that is less relevant is omitted.
def microphone_callback(indata, frames, time, status):
    if status:
        print(status)
    o = indata[:, 0].copy()
    q.put(o)


def translate(recording=True):
    global audio
    if recording:
        while True:
            try:
                audio = np.concatenate((audio, q.get_nowait()))
                if len(audio) >= min_samples:
                    completed_audio, remainder = chunker(audio.copy())
                    if completed_audio is not None:
                        text_chunk = local_transcriber(completed_audio,
                                                       language=source_language,
                                                       prompt=transcript[-prompt_size:])
                        print(text_chunk, flush=True)
                        translation = translator(text_chunk, source_lang=source_language,
                                                 target_lang=target_language)
                        print(translation, flush=True)
                        audio = remainder
            except queue.Empty:
                pass
            if t.time() - start_time > duration_s:
                break
    else:
        ...

q = queue.Queue()

if audio_source == 'mic':
    stream = sd.InputStream(channels=1, samplerate=SAMPLE_RATE, callback=microphone_callback)
    with stream:
        translate()
    print(f"Recording finished", flush=True)
    translate(recording=False)  # Last piece remaining after the end of recording

